# getting latitude and longitude values from controller in rails-geocoder gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, rails-geocoder

Is it possible to get latitude and longitude values in the controller when using [geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) gem in rails?

What am currently doing for getting all nearby location is pass the location name like below.

```
event_address = Event.near(location, 15, order: 'distance')
```

So is there a way to fetch the lat and lng which was used for the above requested location for using later in subsequent requests for same location?

@latitude= #some method

@longitude= #some_method

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Geocoder.coordinates(location)
```

for eg : `Geocoder.coordinates("25 Main St, Cooperstown, NY")`

returns [42.700149, -74.922767]

Answer (score 2):

try with `Event.geocoded` OR

you can use `coordinates` method of geocoder.

Ex.

> Geocoder.coordinates("Your location goes here")

Its return array containing latitude and longitude

Comment: I have tried the coordinates method and it works... where do u got the reference to the geocoded method?