# How to use geocoder with ajax in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Please suggest how to use geocoder with ajax in ruby on rails.  Without submitting the form. I am able to get coordinates after submitting the form

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a minimal code sample and read the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get a good answer by the community here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a form to send location (address) to your controller method:

Form in your View (get_location.html.erb):

```
<%= form_for @location, url: "locations_controller/get_location", remote: true do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_field :address %>
  <%= form.submit  %>
<% end  %>
```

> Above `remote: true` is responsible for sending `ajax` request to your
>   controller method. Here is complete [guide](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for) for form_for and remote requests.

In your controller your method will look like:

```
def get_location
  @coordinates = Geocoder.coordinates(params[:location][:address])
  render js: "alert('Coordinates are #{@coordinates.first}, #{@coordinates.last}')"
end
```

A guide to geocoder can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38075452/getting-latitude-and-longitude-values-from-controller-in-rails-geocoder-gem) and [here](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder)

Side note: Above code patches are just for the idea of how you can achieve your goal.

Comment: Thank you,  it's working

Comment: @SaiBandaru if this answer helps you out then please accept this answer. Thank you.

Comment: @SaiBandaru please upvote :)